# Looking for a data set that shows hospital patients' illnesses and their vital signs, during their stay

Tags: dataset

I'm looking for a data set that shows hospital patients' vital signs (body temperature and/or heart rate, etc.) and their illnesses, over time. Is there such a data set?

For example:
Patient #1, Male, age:35, ..., Diagnosed w/: Heart failure
22:32:10: Temperature:32.1
22:32:20: Temperature:34.2
22:32:30: Temperature:33
22:32:40: Temperature:35

Or:
Patient #2, Female, age:35, ..., Diagnosed w/: Migraine Attack
22:32: Heart Rate:68
22:33: Heart Rate:75
22:34: Heart Rate:69
22:35: Heart Rate:70

I don't have any insistence for the data to come from a hospital. I already have searched some sources but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but here is a collection of clinical data sets that might provide a good alternative:

https://dgroppe.com/2016/11/24/public-clinical-data-science-data-sets/

In particular, you might want to look into the Physionet archive or the Sepsis Patient Event Log.

Comment: The Physionet archive had the "MIMIC Database" indexed and that is the direction that I am going.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking for medical datasets, not only what you have stated in the question, but also some image recognition datasets which need something like CNN.

Try [this one](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease). This dataset contains several medical features including blood sugar, serum cholesterol etc, and wants you to find out the presence of heart disease.

In the meanwhile, there are some medical [competitions](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions) and [datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets) on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), including the famous [Data Science Bowl](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017).